# API call execution order is different in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I can select items from checkboxes and click update. Once I click update I am calling $.ajax() to update the selected entities. In success: of this I am calling another function say function A(). In this there are two $.getJSON() which would populate the updated items grid. Before populating the grid, I will clear (kill) the grid and then add the updated items with checkbox checked.

$.ajax() is asynchronous and $.getJSON() is synchronous.

I am getting required output in Chrome and IE but in firefox I am getting duplicate entities when I select multiple boxes and click update. This is because, when I select two items, it will kill the grid and then add all the updated items to the grid, iterate in each loop and then again kill and add updated items to the grid. The execution order in FF is different and hence the issue. Please elt me know how to handle this. I am afraid I will not be able to make $.getJSON asynchronous. Below is what appears in the console log:

Chrome:

1.Killing grid
 2.initiationg grid
 3.Initiating first getJSON call
4.done with first json call
5.Initiationg second getJSON call
6.done with second json call
7.appending updated data to grid
1.Killing grid
2.initiationg grid
3.Initiating first getJSON call
4.done with first json call
5.Initiationg second getJSON call
6.done with second json call
7.appending updated data to grid

Firefox:

1.Killing grid
2.initiationg grid
3.Initiating first getJSON call
1.Killing grid
2.initiationg grid
3.Initiating first getJSON call
4.done with first json call
5.Initiationg second getJSON call
6.done with second json call
7.appending updated data to grid
4.done with first json call
5.Initiationg second getJSON call
6.done with second json call
7.appending updated data to grid

Comment: *"$.getJSON() is synchronous."* That is not synchronous unless you changed how getJSON works under the covers.

Comment: Showing an example might help.  If your code is assuming an order of asynchronous operations then your code is incorrect.  There is no guaranteed order of completion for asynchronous operations.